# Insalling M.2 nvme SSD and a nornal SSD together

Tags: ssd, installation, nvme

Asus ROG STRIX Z370-H Gaming manual says that the M.2_1 socket is shared between SATA6G_1 and SATA6G_2.

What does this mean? I am putting an nvme ssd in M.2_1 where should I put my normal SSD and should I do anything else in the BIOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you can use either the M.2 slot or those 2 SATA ports. M.2 can use more bandwidth than a single SATA port, so that's why it's using 2.

You'd want to plug the SSD into one of the other four SATA ports, SATA6G_3 through SATA6G_6.  Ports 1 and 2 are at the top of the row of ports, closest to the power connector.
Page 1_2 in the manual shows the ports.

If you don't have your paper manual, you can download from here: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-H-GAMING/HelpDesk_Manual/